# Self Join? Were Staff Who Worked the Previous Week Active 3 Weeks ago - MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, date-arithmetic, domo

I'm trying to add a column to a production hours dataset that will tell if a provider who worked last week was also working three weeks earlier. The current dataset looks something like this:

```
RowID | ProviderID | ClientID |     DOS    |   DOS (Week)  | Hours 
  1   | 1111111111 | 22222222 | 11/2/2020  |   11/1/2020   | 2.5 
  2   | 1111111111 | 33333333 | 11/5/2020  |   11/1/2020   | 1 
  3   | 1111111111 | 44444444 | 10/13/2020 |   10/11/2020  | 3
```

I'm trying to get an extra column 'Active 3 Weeks Prior' with y/n or 1/0 for values. For the above table, let's assume the provider started on 10/13/20. The new column would ideally populate like this:

```
RowID | ProviderID | ClientID |     DOS    |   DOS (Week)  | Hours | Active 3 weeks Prior 
  1   | 1111111111 | 22222222 | 11/2/2020  |   11/1/2020   | 2.5   |   Yes              
  2   | 1111111111 | 33333333 | 11/5/2020  |   11/1/2020   | 1     |   Yes
  3   | 1111111111 | 44444444 | 10/13/2020 |   10/11/2020  | 3     |   No
```

A couple extra tidbits: our org uses Sunday as the start of the week so DOS (Week) is the Sunday prior to the date of service. From what I've been reading so far, it seems like the solution here is some kind of self join, where the base production records are aggregated into weekly hours and compared with that same providerID's records for DOS (Week) - 21.

The trouble I'm having is: whether I'm on the right track in the first place with the self-join and how I would generate the y/n values based on the success or failure to find a matching value. Also, I suspect that joining based on a concatenate of ProviderID and DOS(Week) might be flawed? This is what I've been playing with so far.

Please let me know if I can clarify the question at all or am missing something very obvious. I truly appreciate any help, as I've been trying to figure out the right search terms to get a clue on the answer for a few days now.

Comment: Just show us your code

Comment: Of course, I've done quite a bit of digging and attempting before I posted. When I was looking at the way to ask the question properly, it seemed like providing the sample data was the best method, I'm not sure what else you'd like for the MRE. I did not provide my attempts at code as I believe they are way off. Do you want me to write out the sample data as a CREATE TABLE and INSERT INTO, otherwise I am not sure what I can clarify.

Comment: How is this 'REPRODUCIBLE'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are running MySQL 8.0, you can use window functions and a `range` specification:

```
select t.*,
    (
        max(providerid) over(
            partition by providerid 
            order by dos
            range between interval 3 week preceding and interval 3 week preceding
        ) is not null
    ) as active_3_weeks_before
from mytable t
```

It is not really clear from your explanation and data what you mean by *was also working three weeks earlier*. What the query does is, for each row, to check if another row exists with the same supplier and a `dos` that is exactly 3 week before the `dos` of the current row. This can easily be adapted for some other requirement.

---

**Edit**: if you want to check for *any* record within the last 3 weeks, you would change the window range to:

```
range between interval 3 week preceding and interval 1 day preceding
```

And if you want this in MySQL < 8.0, where window functions are not available, then you would use a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*,
    exists (
        select 1
        from mytable t1
        where 
            t1.providerid = t.provider_id
            and t1.dos >= t.dos - interval 3 week
            and t1.dos <  t.dos
    ) as active_3_weeks_before
from mytable t
```

Comment: Hey, sorry for being unclear. What I meant by working three weeks previously, is, did that providerID have any dates of service worked in the DOS(Week) three weeks prior to the current row. So in the example table, the first two rows would show as 'yes' because the provider worked in the week of 10/11, while the third row would show as 'no' because the provider started in the week of 10/11 and therefore did not work three weeks earlier. I will try your suggestion, thank you!

Comment: Unfortunately I am doing this in DOMO which, due to using MySQL 5.6, does not appear to support the OVER clause...

Comment: This appears to be perfect, thank you so much! Now I'm curious how this solution is so far from the things I was finding - what kind of search terms might have pointed closer to that direction? Everything I looked up regarding comparing rows in the same dataset was pointing towards self-joins. Wish I had seen anything referencing EXISTS in combo with SELECT 1 and WHERE logic. Thank you again.